# Can I use Kafka for chat message pub-sub?

Tags: apache-kafka, chat, publish-subscribe

I am implementing a backend for mobile client that offer chat service include multiple chat room to users.(with Spring boot)

I decided to use Kafka for chat message subscribe and publish because I can't use STOMP with Spring Webflux(that I choose instead of Servlet).

[image]
According to my plan, the exchange of chat messages takes place through the following process. (Suppose `Clients A and B` are in the same chat room.)

1. `client A` connect to `chat server 1` by WebSocket.
2. `client B` connect to `chat server 2` by WebSocket.
3. `chat server1 and 2` subscribe `Kafka topic 'chat'`
4. `client A` send chat message to `chat server 1`.
5. `chat server1` first store chat message to DB, and publish message to `Kafka topic 'chat'`. message contain chat room id, chat content, sender id.
6. `chat server2` receive message from Kafka topic 'chat'.
7. `chat server2` filter message that has chat room id of `client B`had joined.
8. `chat server2` send filtered message to `client B`.

My Question is

I am worried that this is not the usual way. What do ordinary people do?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Kafka will scale well if you have large group chats even though you can do it in theory. If you understand kafka correct, each consumer needs one replica partition to consumer exclusive which means you need a lot partition(redundancy) for chat messages. I don't think it's ideal. In addition, there are other parts of system for a IM app you need to integrate with. However, there are definitely work arounds. for an example, a single consumer to consumer an entire group chat.